# HTML not picking background from local CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have a just started to build a website locally from my pc. The `HTML` code and is picking the styling from the `.css` file that I created, however, it won't take pick the `background-image`. Please see my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\myUser\Documents\website\style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
           <h1>Enter</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `CSS` code:

```
body {
    background: url(C:\Users\gonluis\Documents\website\Images\mainbckgrnd.jpg);
}


.jumbotron {

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 400px;
}
```

The `text-align` and `margin` work fine, however, the `background-image` or `background` regardless whether I use either one won't work. It won't pick it or display it when I pull my page in chrome browser. As you can see I am pointing to the right location where the image is, and can't think of any possible error here. Please help.

Comment: "As you can see I am pointing to the right location where the image is" We dont know where your image is stored. Also what does the network tap in Chrome Developer tools(Press F12) say? 404?

Comment: Put the image in the same folder as the other files and then use a relative path.

Comment: Are you hosting your web page on your current computer? If not, the easiest solution is to upload the image to the same server as the `.html` file and link it from there.EDIT, just saw local PC.

Comment: Well, that is exactly where the image is, in my C:\ in that route that I added, and the network tab in Chrome Dev tool says: "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: if you aren't using XHTML you don't need a close tag for your <link>

Comment: You are missing the Quotes within the brackets so: background: url('C:\Users\gonluis\Documents\website\Images\mainbckgrnd.jpg');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to this

```
background-image: url("C:\Users\gonluis\Documents\website\Images\mainbckgrnd.jpg");
```

Also, make sure that is the actual location of the image.

Or better yet, use your relative path.

```
/website
    index.html
    style.css
    /Images
        mainbckgrnd.jpg
```

Change the code to this

```
background-image: url("Images\mainbckgrnd.jpg");
```

I also notice that you are adding this image to the `body` tag. Make sure the `body` is actually visible so the image can be seen by doing this,

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Ok. When I put the background image in the same folder as the index.html (root.html in my case) it displays. So I maked yours as the answer, however, what would be the reason for this not to work from a different folder, since I may want to include many images in my website but organize them in a different folder rather than have them all scattered about the same folder with the index.html

Comment: You shouldn't be using absolute paths. When you upload this website to a server or even move the main directory then all the links will be broken. You should have the paths relative to the your main directory. You should be able to make a folder inside of your `website` folder named `images` and then place all your images in that folder. Then access them using the relative path of `images/my-image.jpg`